# android: encrypt ready-made sqlite database then use it

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I wrote my sqlite database then i imported to my application,
[I used this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application) ,and it works fine.

after that I recognized that my database is unencrypted, so with any root phone can access it.

so i suggested this way:

1- encrypt my database with key then

2- return it to my application then

3- use encryption key in my code to decrypt database then

4- I use proguard to encrypt my code(because my code has the encryption key).

does this way is correct?

yes, how to do it?

no, what I must to do?

I read about sqlcipher, but I think this technique to encrypt database from creation.

Comment: Check this SO answer by Commonsware - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576229/encrypt-sqlite-database-android

Comment: they said: This will work for new apps starting up with new databases

Comment: sqlcipher is best for encrypt database

Comment: okey,I well use it but how?

Comment: here is example https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/SQLCipherPassphrase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is Full Database Encryption for SQLite

[sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/)

[here is example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/SQLCipherPassphrase)