# How do dictionary developers store their data?

Tags: android, sqlite, security, dictionary, storage

I have created a dictionary, currently store data in sqlite, asset folder. But that way, hacker can access to my database easily. I wonder if there any best way to store data in android, especially for dictionary which contains text and image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQLCipher to encrypt the database.

More here: [SQLEncrpytion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576229/encrypt-sqlite-database-android)