# how to load single and multi tiles (x-y-z) to google map android v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, tiles, offlineapps

I need to offline Google maps road and satellite for my mobile application i have downloaded tiles using 'Easy Google Maps Downloader' now i want to use this tiles in Google play service lib.
i found a help from address [offline-google-maps-google-javascript](http://offlinegooglemapsgooglejavascriptv3.blogspot.com/2013/05/offline-google-maps-google-javascript.html)  that show how to offline google maps but in web application i need to now how to do it in android map applications.

Comment: you can use web view and use web application.

Comment: You go wrong you can use every way to do your job budy!

Comment: Follow This Link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay

Comment: And This One: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay

Comment: And This Link Contain A Very Good Sample And Description: http://guides.cocoahero.com/google-maps-android-custom-tile-providers.html

Comment: Very grateful for your answer, but it did little things to me and I would like more information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576229/encrypt-sqlite-database-android