# ANDROID : Where is .jar files in SQLCipher

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, jar, sqlcipher

I was trying to encrypt my app database following this tutorial here [encrypt sqlite database Android:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576229/encrypt-sqlite-database-android)
I downloaded SQLCipher zip file but i can't find jar files inside it. i only see .so and assets folder.
should i compil them using gradle or what ?. i'm not familliare with gradle yet.
and i'm using eclipse and a genymotion emulator (Android 4.4.4 API 19).

Comment: Eclipse doesn't do Gradle and is officially unsupported for Android development - it is strongly encouraged to use Android Studio

Comment: Besides that, did you try searching for "sqlcipher jar"? First link... https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i looked for it but can't find it in the zip file. i know eclipse is officially unsupported but i feel more cumfortable using it.i downloaded android studio recently and i will start using it soon.

Comment: According to the link you posted, there is no jar **in the zip** the instructions were pretty clear you needed to extract the assets and stuff directly into your project. The link I sent says how to actually make a Jar from the zip

Comment: Yes i can see them now under Building section on that page thank you . I already got jar files from the app example mozarty sent. Thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the sqlcipher example here to find the .so and the .jar

https://github.com/guardianproject/notecipher

I am not sure which version are you looking for

Comment: thank you for replying i will try it. and if the problem is solved i will mark your answer

Comment: i also found the binaries uploaded here by version : 

https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/net.zetetic%3Aandroid-database-sqlcipher/3.3.1-2/view#files/net/zetetic/android-database-sqlcipher/3.3.1-2/

just go to files tab

Comment: i can't find any download link there

Comment: @SaidTagnit ... do you need the **exact path** to the jar?! I found it in 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes where did you found them